# How to avoid copy and paste 3D plot options?

Tags: plotting

I noticed that when I use Plot3D, ContourPlot3D, etc., I usually pass the same many options like this

```
Plot3D[{x + y, x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> Full, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

and

```
ContourPlot3D[x + y - z == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> Full, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Is there a way to avoid copy and paste all the options?

Comment: I am sure this is duplicate. But you can try `SetOptions[{Plot3D, ContourPlot3D}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];` once. Then use `Plot3D` and the options will be read from the above set command automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
opts = Sequence[AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Large, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];

Plot3D[{x + y, x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ##] &[opts]
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach is to create your custom [`PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) with the collection of options you desire:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["myTheme", _] := 
 {ImageSize -> Large, 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> Full, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}}
```

and use it as the option setting for `PlotTheme`:

```
Plot3D[{x + y, x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotTheme -> "myTheme"]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[(x + y)( x - y), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   PlotTheme->"myTheme"]
```

[image]

You can use it in combination with built-in themes:

```
Plot3D[{x + y, x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotTheme->{"myTheme", "Detailed", "ThickSurface"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is the context of `resolvePlotTheme` one of your own creation or the one that exists in the internals?

Comment: @CATrevillian,   ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme`` is an internal function.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I am surprised to see internals that have lowercasing for the first letter of the function